# Ubuntu + PrtSc + AltGr = CRASH

Tags: keyboard, crash, sysrq

On Ubuntu 15.10 and 15.04 on Lenovo t440p when I'm writing a code in Netbeans and accidently click button <kbd>AltGr</kbd> and <kbd>PrtSc</kbd> on same time it's crashed and reboot system. This not take action with fresh installed Ubuntu.

This is backtrace from syslog:

```
Feb  5 19:47:43 mycomputername kernel: [   15.485327] sysrq: SysRq : HELP : loglevel(0-9) reboot(b) crash(c) terminate-all-tasks(e) memory-full-oom-kill(f) kill-all-tasks(i) thaw-filesystems(j) sak(k) show-backtrace-all-active-cpus(l) show-memory-usage(m) nice-all-RT-tasks(n) poweroff(o) show-registers(p) show-all-timers(q) unraw(r) sync(s) show-task-states(t) unmount(u) force-fb(V) show-blocked-tasks(w) dump-ftrace-buffer(z)
Feb  5 19:47:44 mycomputername kernel: [   16.966879] sysrq: SysRq : HELP : loglevel(0-9) reboot(b) crash(c) terminate-all-tasks(e) memory-full-oom-kill(f) kill-all-tasks(i) thaw-filesystems(j) sak(k) show-backtrace-all-active-cpus(l) show-memory-usage(m) nice-all-RT-tasks(n) poweroff(o) show-registers(p) show-all-timers(q) unraw(r) sync(s) show-task-states(t) unmount(u) force-fb(V) show-blocked-tasks(w) dump-ftrace-buffer(z)
Feb  5 19:47:44 mycomputername kernel: [   17.115697] sysrq: SysRq : HELP : loglevel(0-9) reboot(b) crash(c) terminate-all-tasks(e) memory-full-oom-kill(f) kill-all-tasks(i) thaw-filesystems(j) sak(k) show-backtrace-all-active-cpus(l) show-memory-usage(m) nice-all-RT-tasks(n) poweroff(o) show-registers(p) show-all-timers(q) unraw(r) sync(s) show-task-states(t) unmount(u) force-fb(V) show-blocked-tasks(w) dump-ftrace-buffer(z)
Feb  5 19:47:44 mycomputername kernel: [   17.115844] sysrq: SysRq : HELP : loglevel(0-9) reboot(b) crash(c) terminate-all-tasks(e) memory-full-oom-kill(f) kill-all-tasks(i) thaw-filesystems(j) sak(k) show-backtrace-all-active-cpus(l) show-memory-usage(m) nice-all-RT-tasks(n) poweroff(o) show-registers(p) show-all-timers(q) unraw(r) sync(s) show-task-states(t) unmount(u) force-fb(V) show-blocked-tasks(w) dump-ftrace-buffer(z)
Feb  5 19:47:45 mycomputername kernel: [   17.644247] sysrq: SysRq : HELP : loglevel(0-9) reboot(b) crash(c) terminate-all-tasks(e) memory-full-oom-kill(f) kill-all-tasks(i) thaw-filesystems(j) sak(k) show-backtrace-all-active-cpus(l) show-memory-usage(m) nice-all-RT-tasks(n) poweroff(o) show-registers(p) show-all-timers(q) unraw(r) sync(s) show-task-states(t) unmount(u) force-fb(V) show-blocked-tasks(w) dump-ftrace-buffer(z)
Feb  5 19:47:45 mycomputername kernel: [   17.829425] sysrq: SysRq : HELP : loglevel(0-9) reboot(b) crash(c) terminate-all-tasks(e) memory-full-oom-kill(f) kill-all-tasks(i) thaw-filesystems(j) sak(k) show-backtrace-all-active-cpus(l) show-memory-usage(m) nice-all-RT-tasks(n) poweroff(o) show-registers(p) show-all-timers(q) unraw(r) sync(s) show-task-states(t) unmount(u) force-fb(V) show-blocked-tasks(w) dump-ftrace-buffer(z)
Feb  5 19:47:46 mycomputername kernel: [   18.698713] sysrq: SysRq : HELP : loglevel(0-9) reboot(b) crash(c) terminate-all-tasks(e) memory-full-oom-kill(f) kill-all-tasks(i) thaw-filesystems(j) sak(k) show-backtrace-all-active-cpus(l) show-memory-usage(m) nice-all-RT-tasks(n) poweroff(o) show-registers(p) show-all-timers(q) unraw(r) sync(s) show-task-states(t) unmount(u) force-fb(V) show-blocked-tasks(w) dump-ftrace-buffer(z)
Feb  5 19:47:47 mycomputername kernel: [   20.033534] sysrq: SysRq : HELP : loglevel(0-9) reboot(b) crash(c) terminate-all-tasks(e) memory-full-oom-kill(f) kill-all-tasks(i) thaw-filesystems(j) sak(k) show-backtrace-all-active-cpus(l) show-memory-usage(m) nice-all-RT-tasks(n) poweroff(o) show-registers(p) show-all-timers(q) unraw(r) sync(s) show-task-states(t) unmount(u) force-fb(V) show-blocked-tasks(w) dump-ftrace-buffer(z)
Feb  5 19:47:48 mycomputername kernel: [   21.061323] sysrq: SysRq : HELP : loglevel(0-9) reboot(b) crash(c) terminate-all-tasks(e) memory-full-oom-kill(f) kill-all-tasks(i) thaw-filesystems(j) sak(k) show-backtrace-all-active-cpus(l) show-memory-usage(m) nice-all-RT-tasks(n) poweroff(o) show-registers(p) show-all-timers(q) unraw(r) sync(s) show-task-states(t) unmount(u) force-fb(V) show-blocked-tasks(w) dump-ftrace-buffer(z)
```

How can I disable PrtSc or prevent to accidently clicking PrintScreen on Lenovo keyboard? Or what's problem on this backtrace?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### The problem:

On your keyboard, the <kbd>Print Screen (PrtSc)</kbd> and <kbd>System Request (SysRq)</kbd> are on the same physical button, like on most layouts I know.

The key combinations <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysRq</kbd>+<kbd>[SPECIFIC LETTER]</kbd> are generally known as **Magic SysRq Commands** which directly send commands to the kernel.

They're mainly used as a safer alternative to a cold reset if the system is completely crashed, because there are e.g. commands to sync and unmount the file system to prevent damage and data corruption and to reset/reboot (if you press <kbd>B</kbd> as 3rd key) or power off (3rd key <kbd>O</kbd>). More information and a full list of combinations, even with respect to different keyboard layouts, can be found in the corresponding Wikipedia article [Magic SysRq Key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key).

So what you're accidentally doing is to directly send the kernel the command to reboot, and that's what it does.

---

### The solution:

*Depending on how your kernel was compiled*, you are however able to specify on which SysRq commands the kernel should listen when the system is running. I just tested this on 15.10 with kernel `4.2.0-27-generic` and it worked, but it would be nice to learn since when or for what kernels this is enabled. Please comment if you know.

- #### Find out the current <kbd>SysRq</kbd> command filter value:

  We can learn which <kbd>SysRq</kbd> commands are currently enabled by checking the content of the virtual file `/proc/sys/kernel/sysrq`:

  ```
  cat /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq
  ```

  The result will be a number that must be interpreted like this:

  ```
  0 - disable SysRq
  1 - enable SysRq completely
  >1 - bitmask of enabled SysRq functions:
      2 - control of console logging level
      4 - control of keyboard (SAK, unraw)
      8 - debugging dumps of processes etc.
      16 - sync command
      32 - remount read-only
      64 - signalling of processes (term, kill, oom-kill)
      128 - reboot/poweroff
      256 - nicing of all RT tasks
  ```

  My default value when I'm on the desktop is `176`, which is `128+32+16`. So according to the table above, I can reboot, poweroff, sync and remount file systems to read-only.
- #### Disable all <kbd>SysRq</kbd> commands:

  Execute the command below and try whether the <kbd>SysRq</kbd> shortcuts still work afterwards (e.g. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysRq</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to reset/reboot):

  ```
  echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq
  ```

  This should disable all <kbd>SysRq</kbd> commands for the current session, until you reboot the next time.
- #### Enable all <kbd>SysRq</kbd> commands:

  To manually *enable all* <kbd>SysRq</kbd> commands, we write the value `1` to the same virtual file instead:

  ```
  echo 1 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq
  ```
- #### Enable previous default <kbd>SysRq</kbd> command filter:

  You restore your default configuration by either rebooting, or if you checked and remembered the value before tweaking it, you can set that value again instead of `0`/`1` to enable/disable all commands.

  So in my case where the original value was `176`, I would run:

  ```
  echo 176 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq
  ```

Comment: Your solution only holds until the next reboot. The proper permanent solution is to edit `/etc/sysctl.d/10-magic-sysrq.conf` file.

Comment: Hooray. This happened to me three times and this answer (plus comment by @Ruslan) saves a lot of pain.